# Running a Timer that counts down in background when app isnt the focus? Swift

Tags: swift, timer, background

I want my countdown timer to suspend and then resume when the app leaves / returns to focus, using the time away to calculate how much time should be deducted.

I am using the app delegate file (not sure thats the right location? or if they are meant to be in the view controllers file as functions of their own?)

Issue is im getting a lot of errors such as:

> Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'restTimer'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'nextFireDate'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'selector'

restTimer was declared as a timer in my view controllers file but when i tried these blocks in that file i got an equal number of errors for unresolved identifiers

and using the following 2 code blocks

```
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let t = self.restTimer else { return }
        nextFireDate = t.fireDate
        t.invalidate()
```

and

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let n = nextFireDate else { return }
        let howMuchLonger = n.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate())
        if howMuchLonger < 0 {
            print("Should have already fired \(howMuchLonger) seconds ago")
            target!.performSelector(selector!)
        } else {
            print("should fire in \(howMuchLonger) seconds")
            Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(howMuchLonger, target: target!, selector: selector!, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
}
```

UPDATE: Added full views code due to issue incorporating the answer

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RestController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var restRemainingCountdownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var setsRemainingCountdownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfSetsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfRestLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var adjustSetsStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var adjustRestStepper: UIStepper!
    
    var startDate: Date!
    let startDateKey = "start.date"
    let interval = TimeInterval(20)
    
    var restTimer: Timer!
    var restCount = 0
    var setCount = 0
    var selectedTime = 1
    var selectedSets = 1
    
    private let resignDateKey = "resign.date"
    
    @IBAction func endSetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (setCount > 0){
            setCount -= 1
            setsRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(setCount)
        }
        handleTimer()
    }
    
    @IBAction func setStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        numberOfSetsLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
        self.setCount = Int(sender.value)
        self.selectedSets = setCount
        setsRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(setCount)
    }
    
    @IBAction func restStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        numberOfRestLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
        let timeMinSec = timeFormatted(totalSeconds: Int(sender.value)*60)
        restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = timeMinSec
        self.selectedTime = Int(sender.value)
        restCount = self.selectedTime * 60
    }
    
    @IBAction func resetSetsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        setCount = Int(adjustSetsStepper.value)
        setsRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(setCount)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        numberOfSetsLabel.text = String(selectedSets)
        numberOfRestLabel.text = String(selectedTime)
        
        createTimer(interval: interval)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    @objc private func willResignActive(notification: Notification) {
        print("resigning")
        guard restTimer.isValid else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: startDateKey)
            return
        }
        restTimer.invalidate()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: startDateKey)
    }
    
    @objc private func didBecomeActive(notification: Notification) {
        print("resume")
        if let startDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: startDateKey) as? Date {
            let elapsed = -startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
            print("elpased time: \(elapsed) remaining time: \(interval - elapsed)")
            if elapsed > interval {
                timerUp()
            } else {
                createTimer(interval: interval - elapsed)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createTimer (interval: TimeInterval) {
        restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval , repeats: false) {[weak self] _ in
            self?.timerUp()
        }
        startDate = Date()
    }
    
    private func timerUp() {
        print("At least \(interval) seconds has elapsed")
    }

    
    func handleSets() {
        
        if (setCount > 0) {
            
            self.restCount = self.selectedTime * 60
        }
        handleTimer()
    }
    
    func handleTimer() {
        
        if (restTimer?.isValid ?? false) {
            
            restTimer?.invalidate()
            restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(RestController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            
        } else {
            
            restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(RestController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
    
    func updateTimer() {
        if (restCount > 0){
            restCount -= 1
        } else if (restCount == 0){
            restTimer?.invalidate()
            
        }
        restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = timeFormatted(totalSeconds: restCount)
    }
    
    func timeFormatted(totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
        let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
        let minutes: Int = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the AppDelegate for this because it also posts notifications.  You can use the AppDelegate if you want.  Here is code using notifications:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController{
        private let startDateKey = "start.date"
        private let interval = TimeInterval(20)
        private var startDate: Date!
        private var timer: Timer!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            createTimer(interval: interval)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        }

        deinit {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        }

        @objc private func willResignActive(notification: Notification) {
            print("resigning")
            guard timer.isValid else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: startDateKey)
                return
            }
            timer.invalidate()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: startDateKey)
        }

        @objc private func didBecomeActive(notification: Notification) {
            print("resume")
            if let startDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: startDateKey) as? Date {
                let elapsed = -startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
                print("elpased time: \(elapsed) remaining time: \(interval - elapsed)")
                if elapsed > interval {
                    timerUp()
                } else {
                    createTimer(interval: interval - elapsed)
                }
            }
        }

        private func createTimer (interval: TimeInterval) {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval , repeats: false) {[weak self] _ in
                self?.timerUp()
            }
            startDate = Date()
        }

        private func timerUp() {
            print("At least \(interval) seconds has elapsed")
        }

    }
```

Comment: is there a method that uses all swift and not obj c? I added in this code and it doesn't do anything? I assume i need to integrate my timer variable somewhere?

Comment: @objc is swift; its a compiler directive to use the Objective C run time which you need because notifications takes a #selector and by default private swift functions don't use the Objective C runtime or the Swift Vtable dispatch because they cannot be inherited from and so they are not dynamic.  You need to save your timer in Userdefaults where I an saving the date and then recreate it with the appropriate time interval or fire immediately if that interval has passed.

Comment: thanks sorry i misunderstood. How would i go about saving and recreating the timer?

Comment: i added it but i dont think its interacting with my code, i have updated the OP with my full VC for reference with your code added in, i think i see the conflicts between timers but didnt want to loose my timers functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot rely on the fact that the app will remain in memory while it is in the background. Thus, you should archive all the data you need to **recreate** the timer at the exact point.

For example, in `applicationWillResignActive`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: t.nextFireDate forKey:"NextFireDate")
```

and in `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
if let fireDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "NextFireDate") {
    // setup a timer with the correct fire date
}
```

Comment: does this go in app delegate or in the VC that has the timer? im getting errors placing it in the app delegate

Comment: App delegate. There are no errors in the code, so if you define your variables correctly, it should do the job.

Comment: where are you supposed to define fireDate? and is 't' my timers variable name? in this case restTimer, and how do i set up a timer with the correct fire date? my timer is in my viewController

Comment: If you do not know how to make a variable known to your app delegate you should perhaps open another question. This is pretty basic stuff...

Comment: its not something ive done before so ill look into it, only been learning a week!